# Add function to Git bash from txt

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell, github

I am working with GIT bash.
And I have this file "proxy_functions.txt":

```
 function proxy(){
     echo -n "username:"
     read -e username
     echo -n "password:"
     read -es password
     export http_proxy="http://$username:$password@proxy:8080/"
     export https_proxy=$http_proxy
     export ftp_proxy=$http_proxy
     export rsync_proxy=$http_proxy
     export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
     echo -e "\nProxy environment variable set."
 }

 function proxyoff(){
     unset HTTP_PROXY
     unset http_proxy
     unset HTTPS_PROXY
     unset https_proxy
     unset FTP_PROXY
     unset ftp_proxy
     unset RSYNC_PROXY
     unset rsync_proxy
     echo -e "\nProxy environment variable removed."
 }
```

loaded in my GIT bash in order to, when i write "proxy" in the shell and then my user and pass of the proxy to have the GIT bash ready to push things to my online repo in GIT hub...

It used to work fine but now I think i mess it up beacuse when I write "proxy" in GIT bash it says

```
bash: proxy: command not found
```

How can I reinsert the command in GIT bash from the txt file "proxy_functions.txt" where it is written?

Comment: Did you source the `.bashrc` after you added the function()

Comment: It's very likely.... I have to modify something in that file?

Comment: I have just searched and I only find "bash.bashrc" file in the directory where GIT is installed, is it the same file you're referring to?

Comment: In which file did you add the function `proxy()` in your git bash configuration?

Comment: :(  I don't know, the mate of mine did the job and now I can't ask him. I only know that when I use GIT bash, i type "proxy" and it executes the function in "proxy_functions.txt"

Comment: Try and locate a file `.bashrc` in your `$HOME` path. If the function definition is present there, you need to type `bash` or `source $HOME/.bashrc` from the command-line for the function to take effect in your shell.

Comment: Yes, it worked!!! Thank you!

Comment: It seems a bit odd to name that file with a `.txt` extension. I'd probably call it something like `proxy_functions.bash`. The system doesn't care how you name the file, but it's best for the name to tell you what kind of file it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to source the `proxy_functions.txt` script in your `bash.bashrc` file. So, if for instance `proxy_functions.txt` is located at `C:\Users\Arcones\proxy_functions.txt`, then you will need a line in your `bash.bashrc` file that says:

```
source C:\Users\Arcones\proxy_functions.txt
```